# span grid in bootstrap v2.3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scaffolding

I am using Bootstrap v2.3.0 to design footer content. I am trying to use the bootstrap grid to order my columns. In v2.3.0 by using span(adding up to 12 cols), my columns are not covering the entire row.
Only in 980px screen, it's covering the entire row. But when screen size gets larger than 980px, some space is getting left or uncovered on the right side. I want the 3rd span part to be in the extreme right of the screen.

Please refer to the image for the output of my code.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlfyQ.png)

Actually I want my output like below code:
[Required or Expected output][1]

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/3.0.0/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/3.0.0/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <div style="float:right;">.col-sm-6_Part-2</div>
      <div style="float:right; padding-right: 100px">.col-sm-6_Part-1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should I use to get it correct? Please help. Thanks in advance !!

Below is the current/wrong code.

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4" style="background-color:lavender;">span4</div>
      <div class="span4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">span4</div>
      <div class="span4" style="background-color:lavender;">span4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: and why still using the V2 when we have the V3 and the V4?

Comment: sorry to say, old code is already present in my project and I need to change the footer content acc. to some guidlenes now and delivier by Dec-2019 end. I have to make it responsive as well. I tried to upgrade the bootstrap to v4.3 but it affected our application which needs significant time to upgrade the code. I guess it will be upgraded later.

Comment: @AashishNayak "I want my output like below code: " you have the code then what do you want???

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, Sorry for being unclear, code under 'required output' section is in Bootstrap v3.0.0. Actually I want the same type of output in Bootstrap v2.3.0. which I was unable to do correctly.

Comment: @AashishNayak you could have used bootstarp 4 grid for doing it in minimum amount of code.There is a lot of redundant code in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. I know you are using bootstrap v2 and I understand why but do this.

Do this

```html
<div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
```

I did inline style to not destroy other parts of code because bootstrap v2 is really old and I don't know how it will work if you put this CSS globally for every `row` element

It will put `first span` to left `second span` to center and `third span` to right of the screen.

Is this what you want to do? If not then post in comments.

**UPDATE**

If you only want to push the third element to the right and leave other two on their current places you can do this

```html
<div class="span4" style="background-color:lavender; float: right">span4</div>
```

It will float that element to the far right of its parent

**UPDATE 2**

Based on new info I got from comment here is the solution

```html
<div class="row">
```

You need

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
```

`row-fluid` will take the whole width of parent and spans will stretch

This is a bootstrap 2 feature. Read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

Comment: In ur later code change, space is being left between 2nd & 3rd span element.

Comment: isn't that what you want? to push the third element to the far right? ```I want the 3rd span part to be in the extreme right of the screen.```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I think ur later code will work. I have added my required output's image in question. Please refer and help.

Comment: oh. wait. I just saw it. let me see that. I will get back to you soon

Comment: I edited the answer. Check it out and see if it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks a Lot !! 
It helped. I think in v2.3.0 span elements don't stack to each other leaving some margin in between. Anyway I can fill that with my background colour.

And can you help me in using Responsive utility classes:  '.visible-phone' & '.hidden-phone'.
Its working in v2.3.2 but it is also shown in v2.3.0 doc.

Else I can use the media query.

Comment: If you want to make it fully responsive I suggest using media-query for that because bootstrap V2 is really old and it might have a lot of bugs for newer browsers. If the answer helped please accept it so it can help other users as well :)

Comment: System not accepting the Upvote from me as I am a new user. Any other way to accept your answer.

Comment: not upvote. I don't care about reputation. You need to click green tick underneath the downvote button so others can see that it helped and try it on their problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203379/discussion-between-aashish-nayak-and-mileta-dulovic).

Comment: Your answer is unclear to the point where I failed to see it actually contains the correct one (that's why I added mine). Also note inline styles cannot be applied responsively and is generally regarded as bad practice. You basically wrapped a good answer into questionable code and made the useful part difficult to find. It would be useful for future visitors if you cleaned the answer up. Please only leave the part which actually answers the question and I'll remove my answer (which does what yours doesn't: answers efficiently).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu that would be true if this was not programming. One problem has many solutions. I won't change my answer and I am not asking you to remove yours because that float might help someone who wants only one item to go far right. It's true that inline style is not always good but it depends on what you want to achieve. Bootstrap 2 is not using flex so changing every row globally to display: flex might break whole app and in this case display: flex will be there on every screen if you want responsiveness so inline will work just fine.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu as he stated that this is an older website and it is using bootstrap 2 (Currently it is on version 4 and version 5 is coming out soon) inline styles are actually preferred here. I also notices faster loading when using inline CSS for smaller things. Also. is it better to have a CSS file full of ```!important``` tags or few inline styles in HTML when working on an old project that you didn't make?

Comment: I'm not going to convince you inline styles are bad practice. You'll probably learn it as you get more experienced. I simply thought it would be helpful for you to know the useful part of your answer is currently obfuscated by the not so useful part, to the point where I (being a fairly seasoned FE developer) wasn't able to find the useful part at first read (and felt the need to add a useful answer myself). I didn't mean to criticize, I meant to help but, apparently, help is neither needed, nor wanted. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `row` class with `row-fluid`:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:lavender;">span4</div>
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">span4</div>
    <div class="span4" style="background-color:lavender;">span4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this:
minimum amount of code:

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavender;">span4</div>
                <div class="col-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">span4</div>
                <div class="col-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavender;">span4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

check :https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/ut8d0j3m/